# How to get childs of firebase database to an android listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have been searching for this but have not managed to find what I was looking for.
[image]

Here is an image of what I have in firebase.

I need to show it in the listview but also I need to show it dynamically. Such as if there are 30 links it should show 30 items in the listview and if there are 50 links here in Firebase the listview should have 50 items.

What would be the best possible way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    dref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

This will show all the data of child in a listview